# Error while PrePopulating Name in Opportunity

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

[image]I want to prepoulate Name field on opportunity with text as "System Generated".

I have written created a VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="DefaultOpprtunityNameController" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

and its controller as

```
public with sharing class DefaultOpprtunityNameController {

public DefaultOpprtunityNameController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}


public PageReference redirect() {
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/006/e');
    Map<String, String> m = pr.getParameters();
    // Keep existing parameters
    m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
    // Add Opportunity name parameter
    m.put('opp3', '<System Generated>');
    m.put('opp11', 'Requested Info');
    m.put('opp12', '25');
    // Turn off the override so you go to the default UI page (and not an infinite loop)
    m.put('nooverride', '1');
    return pr;
}
```

}

And overrided standerd Opportunity "New" button with the above VF page

But I am getting an error

> Error: Invalid Data.
>   Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please
>   click Save again to confirm your change.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you click the "New" button or when you click the "Save" button after clicking "New"?

Comment: I am getting error on click of new button on opportunity tab landing page.

Comment: Wondering if it has to do with setting the probability to a string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be with grabbing the parameters from the page where the "New" button is clicked. Try eliminating this line and that should eliminate the error.

```
m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
```

Comment: That what I was seeing as well. I got the error to go away by removing the `save_new` parameter.