# The page you submitted was invalid for your session

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, session

EDIT:

[image]
I have overridden the New button in Case object and opening a Visualforce page but if I open the page using preview VFP I'm not getting the error and its happening only when I click on NEW button.

I have looked at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103697/the-page-you-submitted-was-invalid-for-your-session-please-click-save-again-to) but did not help me fix the issue i'm having.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" extensions="caseExt" action="{!redirectPage}">
<apex:form id="form">
    ......
    ......

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference redirectPage() 
{
  PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
  Map<String, String> param = p.getParameters();
  param.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());                       
  param.put('nooverride', '1');                        
  page.setRedirect(true);
  return page;

}
```

> Error: Invalid Data.
>   Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please
>   click Save again to confirm your change.

Comment: `Security Controls > Session Settings` this should solve your issue ?

Comment: nope it did not solve my issue

Comment: Try removing the line param.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());

Comment: Not sure which parameter is causing the issue but I remember someone else running into this issue before.

Comment: Saw your comment on my question from yesterday, but it looks like Jenny has figured it out already. What you need to do now is review all the parameters you are getting from the current page using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()` - using debug logs with system.debug() is how I would check that.

Comment: Found the other question, it looks like it was the save_new parameter that needed to be removed - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92227/error-while-prepopulating-name-in-opportunity/92257#92257

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line here `param.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());` and in particular with the `save_new` parameter that is being added to the URL causing the error.
Similar issue here,  [Error while PrePopulating Name in Opportunity](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92227/error-while-prepopulating-name-in-opportunity/92257#92257)