# The page you submitted was invalid for your session Error

Tags: visualforce, error

After reviewing all other posts related to this error I could find on stackexchange and on other salesforce forums I still couldn't find any similar scenario to mine. 
Exact Error :

> The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please click save
>   again to confirm your change.

The class and visualforce page were written by the previous developer which is no longer working here and I'm really lost on how to stop this error from happening since I cannot reproduce the error and  MiddleOffice can't save all the changes they perform and can lose like 15-20 minutes filling this visualforce page to only face this error when they Click Update button (it happens sometimes, we couldn't figure out a pattern).

This are the codes (I upload a short version, cutting comparable interfaces and irrelevant stuff so it isn't so hard to read, it's still a pretty big chunk of code tho)

> Class Code

```
public with sharing class FarmingCampaignDetailController {
    public List<Wrapped>              accounts {get;set;}
    public AccountCampaignMember__c   cached   {get;set;}
    private static final integer monthsET = 6;
    public static Set<id> idProfileFxSpecialist {get;set;}
    public FarmingCampaignDetailController(){
        List<Campaign> camx = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name LIKE '%Farming%' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
        cached =  new AccountCampaignMember__c(CampaignRef__c = camx[0] != null ? camx[0].Id:null);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){            
        Date auxDate = System.today().addMonths(-monthsET);
        accounts = new List<Wrapped>();
        if(cached.CampaignRef__c == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Please, select a Campaign to work with.'));
            } else {
                Map<Id,Decimal> idTraded = new Map<Id,Decimal>(); 
                for(AccountCampaignMember__c acm : [SELECT Id,
                   CampaignRef__r.Name,
                   Comments__c,
                   FXRating__c,
                   LevelOfSatisfaction__c,
                   Excluded__c,
                   LevelOfSatisfactionDetails__c,
                   EstimatedNextTrade__c,
                   FarmingType__c,
                   Status__c,
                   UserRef__c,
                   MainTopic__c,
                   CommentToReview__c,
                   AccountRef__c,
                   AccountRef__r.Churn__c,
                   AccountRef__r.Name, 
                   AccountRef__r.Phone, 
                   AccountRef__r.Company_Email__c, 
                   AccountRef__r.OwnerId, 
                   AccountRef__r.Owner.Name, 
                   AccountRef__r.Days_since_last_activity__c, 
                   AccountRef__r.DaysSinceLastTrade__c, 
                   AccountRef__r.TradingFrequence__c,
                   AccountRef__r.Annual_FX__c,
                   AccountRef__r.AvoidFarming__c,
                   AccountRef__r.ClientSegmentation__c,
                   AccountRef__r.UnpaidAmount__c
                   FROM AccountCampaignMember__c
                   WHERE CampaignRef__c = :cached.CampaignRef__c]){
                    accounts.add(new Wrapped(acm));
                    idTraded.put(acm.AccountRef__c, 0);                               
                }
                for (AggregateResult aR: [SELECT SUM(Normalized_amount__c)total, Client__c client
                  FROM Transaction__c
                  WHERE Client__r.isActive__c=true
                  AND Client__r.Company_Account_Status__c!='Suspended'
                  AND Signing_Date__c >= :auxDate
                  AND Status__c!= 'Canceled'
                  AND RecordType.Name='Trading'
                  AND Normalized_Amount__c > 0
                  AND Client__c IN :idTraded.keySet()
                  GROUP BY ROLLUP(Client__c)
                  ORDER BY SUM(Normalized_amount__c) DESC]){
                    if(aR.get('client')!=null){
                        idTraded.put((Id) aR.get('client'), (Decimal) aR.get('total'));
                    }
                }

                for(Wrapped w : accounts){
                    if(idTraded.containsKey(w.member.AccountRef__c)){
                        w.traded = idTraded.get(w.member.AccountRef__c);
                        w.fxGap  = (w.member.AccountRef__r.Annual_FX__c > 0)? w.member.AccountRef__r.Annual_FX__c - (w.traded*12/monthsET) : 0;  
                    }
                }            
            }
            accounts.sort();
        }
            public PageReference doSaveChanges() {
                idProfileFxSpecialist = new Set<id>();
                for(Profile P: [SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE '%FX Specialist%' OR Name LIKE 'Associate' OR Name LIKE 'Country Manager' OR NAme LIKE 'BDM' OR NAME LIKE 'MRR']) {
                    idProfileFxSpecialist.add(P.id);
                }
                Map<Id,String> accountOwners  = new Map<Id,String>();
                Map<Id,Wrapped> accountACM    = new Map<Id,Wrapped>();
                List<Lead> leadsToUpsert = new List<Lead>();
                List<Opportunity> OppsToUpsert = new List<Opportunity> ();
                List<AccountCampaignMember__c> acmToUpdate = new List<AccountCampaignMember__c>();
                List <Account> AccountsToUpdate = new List <Account> ();
                Set <id> idsAccountsToUpdateChurn = new Set<id> ();
                for(Wrapped wr : accounts){ 
                    if(wr.needsUpdate && (!idProfileFxSpecialist.contains(UserInfo.getProfileId())||(idProfileFxSpecialist.contains(UserInfo.getProfileId())&&wr.member.AccountRef__r.OwnerId == UserInfo.getUserId()))){
                        wr.member.Status__c =(wr.member.Excluded__c)? 'excluded':(wr.unsuccessful)?'Not Reached':(wr.Emailed && wr.member.Status__c!='Completed')?'Emailed':'Completed';
                        if(wr.churn) idsAccountsToUpdateCHurn.add(wr.member.AccountRef__c);
                        acmToUpdate.add(wr.member);
                        accountACM.put(wr.member.Id, wr); 
                        accountOwners.put(wr.member.AccountRef__r.OwnerId, '');
                        if(!String.isBlank(wr.member.MainTopic__c)){
                            for(String s : String.valueOf(wr.member.MainTopic__c).split(';')){
                                if(idProfileFxSpecialist.contains(UserInfo.getProfileId())) {
                                    OppsToUpsert.add(createFOpportunity(wr.member,wr.member.CampaignRef__c,s));    
                                }
                                else leadsToUpsert.add(createFLead(wr.member, s));
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
                AccountsToUpdate = [SELECT id,Churn__c FROM Account WHERE id in: idsAccountsToUpdateChurn];
                for(Account A: AccountsToUpdate) {
                    A.churn__c = TRUE;
                }
                update AccountsToUpdate;
                if(acmToUpdate.size()==0){
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please, select accounts to be updated.'));
                    return null;
                }

                Boolean errors=false;
                for (Database.SaveResult sR : Database.update(acmToUpdate,false)){
                    if(!sR.isSuccess()){
                        errors=true;
                        accountACM.remove(sR.getId());
                        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()){
                            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'The Account with Id '+sR.getId()+' cannot be updated because due to: '+err.getMessage()+'.'));
                        }
                    }           
                }

                if(leadsToUpsert.size()>0){
                    for (Database.SaveResult uR : Database.insert(leadsToUpsert,false)){
                        if(!uR.isSuccess()){
                            errors=true;
                            for(Database.Error err : uR.getErrors()){
                                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Some Leads couldn\'t be upserted due to: '+err.getMessage()+'.'));
                            }
                        }               
                    }
                }
                if(OppsToUpsert.size()>0){
                    for (Database.SaveResult uR : Database.insert(OppsToUpsert,false)){
                        if(!uR.isSuccess()){
                            errors=true;
                            for(Database.Error err : uR.getErrors()){
                                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Some opportunities couldn\'t be upserted due to: '+err.getMessage()+'.'));
                            }
                        }               
                    }
                }  

                if(accountACM.keySet().size()>0){
                    Set<Id> noEmails = new Set<Id>();
                    List<Task> tasksToInsert = new List<Task>();
                    for (Wrapped w : accountACM.values()){
                        if(!w.member.excluded__c)tasksToInsert.add( new Task( ActivityDate              = System.today(),
                         Did_you_speak_with_CFO__c = w.talkWithCFO ? 'Yes':'No',
                         WhatId                    = w.member.AccountRef__c,
                         Status                    = 'Completed',
                         Subject                   = w.unsuccessful? w.member.CampaignRef__r.Name+'_Contact Attempt' :(w.emailed)? w.member.CampaignRef__r.Name +'_Email':w.member.CampaignRef__r.Name+'_Farming Call',
                         Type                      = w.unsuccessful?'Contact Attempt':(w.emailed)?'Email':'Farming Call',
                         Description               = w.member.Comments__c));
                        if(w.unsuccessful) noEmails.add(w.member.Id);                                                    
                    }

                    for (Database.SaveResult sR : Database.insert(tasksToInsert,false)){
                        if(!sR.isSuccess()){
                            errors=true;
                            accountACM.remove(sR.getId());
                            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()){
                                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'The activity with Id '+sR.getId()+' cannot be inserted because due to: '+err.getMessage()+'. Please, save an screenshot and notify an administrator.'));
                            }
                        }           
                    }

                    for(Id idx : noEmails){
                        accountACM.remove(idx);
                    }
                }

                if(accountACM.keySet().size()>0){

                    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();             
                    for (User u : [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :accountOwners.keySet()]){
                        accountOwners.put(u.Id, u.email);
                    }

                    for (Wrapped wd : accountACM.values()){
                        if(!wd.member.excluded__c) {
                            List<String> recipients   = new List<String> {accountOwners.get(wd.member.AccountRef__r.OwnerId)};
                            String body = label.FarmingEmail.replace('[OWNER],', wd.member.AccountRef__r.Owner.Name + ',\r\r')
                            .replace('[ACCNAME]', wd.member.AccountRef__r.Name )
                            .replace('[COMMENTS]','\r\r'+wd.member.Comments__c+'\r\rLevel of Satisfaction: '+wd.member.LevelOfSatisfaction__c+'\r\rEstimated next Trade: '+wd.member.EstimatedNextTrade__c+'\r\r')
                            .replace('[EMAIL]', 'https://eu2.salesforce.com/'+wd.member.AccountRef__c+'\r\r');
                            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                            email.setToAddresses(recipients);
                            email.setPlainTextBody(body);
                            email.setSubject('New farming call');
                            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);                     
                            emails.add(email);                              
                        }

                    }
                    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
                }               

                if(!errors) ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Records have been updated successfully.'));
                init();
                return null;                    
            }

            public Lead createFLead(AccountCampaignMember__c member, String mainTopicLine){
// nonrelevantcode
            }

            public static Opportunity createFOpportunity(AccountCampaignMember__c member, Id campaignId, String mainTopicLine){
// nonrelevantcode
            }

            public class Wrapped implements Comparable{

                public AccountCampaignMember__c member {get;set;}    
                public Boolean needsUpdate     {get;set;}  
                public Boolean churn           {get;set;}
                public Boolean Emailed     {get;set;}  
                public Boolean unsuccessful    {get;set;}  
                public Boolean talkWithCFO     {get;set;}  
                public Decimal fxGap           {get;set;}  
                public Decimal traded          {get;set;}  

                private String keyCode         {get;set;}  

                public Wrapped (AccountCampaignMember__c acm){
                    member       = acm;
                    keyCode      = acm.UserRef__c + '-' + acm.Id;
                    Emailed  = false;
                    churn        = acm.AccountRef__r.Churn__c;

                    unsuccessful = false;
                    needsUpdate  = false;
                    talkWithCFO  = false;
                    fxGap        = 0;
                    traded       = 0;
                }

                public void recalculateKeys(){
                    this.keyCode = this.member.UserRef__c + '-' + this.member.Id;
                }    
    }
}
```

> Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="FarmingCampaignDetailController">
<head>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script>
   $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function () {
    reload();
});
function reload(){
    $j(".data").hide();
    $j("[id$=mlktp]").hide()    
    $j(".header").click(function () {
        if($j("[id!=xx]")){
            $j(this).next(".data").slideToggle(200);
        }
    });
}

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
    <body>

    <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Farming Management" title="Farming Management Page for Middle Office"/>
      <apex:form id="theForm"> 
      <apex:pageMessages id="messages2"></apex:pageMessages>       
        <apex:pageBlock title="Data input" id="theDataInput"> 
            <apex:outputPanel id="LookUpCampaign">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="UserSelection1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="Campaign">
                    <apex:outputLabel >Campaign:</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField style="width:200pt" value="{!cached.CampaignRef__c}" id="SalesP" required="false" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>             
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom"> 
                <apex:actionStatus id="loadingSearch" ><apex:facet name="start"><apex:image value="/img/loading.gif"/></apex:facet></apex:actionStatus>                   
                <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!init}" id="refreshButton" rerender="theForm" status="loadingSearch" oncomplete="reload();"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <apex:commandButton value="Reassign" action="{!doChangeAssignments}" id="AssignButton" rerender="theForm" status="loadingSearch" oncomplete="reload();"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!doSaveChanges}" id="saveButton" rerender="theForm" status="loadingSearch" oncomplete="reload();"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>                   
        </apex:pageBlock> 

<div style="padding-bottom:15pt;">
<table class="tg" id="theaddrs">
  <tr>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Called</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Name</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Phone</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Email</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">FX Rating</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Days since<br/>last activity</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Days since<br/>last trade</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Trading<br/>frequence</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Traded last<br/>6 months</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Fx Gap</th>    
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Farming Type</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Owner</th>
    <th  style="text-align:center;">Assigned To</th>
  </tr>

  <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="acc"> 
   <tbody class="header">
   <tr>
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;"><apex:outputText value="{!IF(acc.member.Status__c=='Completed','✔✔', IF(acc.member.Status__c=='Not Reached','✔',IF(acc.member.Status__c=='Excluded','✘',IF(acc.member.Status__c=='Emailed','@','⃝'))))}"/></td>    
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;"><apex:outputLink style="{!IF(acc.member.AccountRef__r.AvoidFarming__c, 'color:red;', '')}" id="AccountNameLink" target="_blank" value="/{!acc.member.AccountRef__c}" >{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.Name}</apex:outputLink></td>
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.Phone}</td>
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.Company_Email__c}</td>
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.FXRating__c}</td>
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.Days_since_last_activity__c}</td>
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.DaysSinceLastTrade__c}</td>    
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.TradingFrequence__c}</td>    
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!ROUND(acc.traded,0)} €</td>    
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!ROUND(acc.fxGap,0)} €</td>    
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.FarmingType__c}</td>    
    <td style="background:#f2f2f2;">{!acc.member.AccountRef__r.Owner.Name}</td>
    <td id="xx" style="background:#f2f2f2;"> <apex:outputField value="{!acc.member.UserRef__c}"/></td>  
  </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="data">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" ><b>Biz Opportunity</b> <apex:inputField value="{!acc.member.MainTopic__c}"/></td>
    <td colspan="2" ><b>Estimated next trade </b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div>  <apex:inputField value="{!acc.member.EstimatedNextTrade__c}"/></td>
    <td colspan="2" ><b>Level of satisfaction</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div>  <apex:inputField value="{!acc.member.LevelOfSatisfaction__c}"/></td>
    <td colspan="2" > <b>Assign to</b><div style="display:inline-block;"><apex:inputField value="{!acc.member.UserRef__c}"/></div> </td>    
    <td colspan="1" ><b>Talk KDM?</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div> <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!acc.talkWithCFO}"/></td>
    <td colspan="1" ><b>Emailed</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div> <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!acc.Emailed}"/></td>
    <td colspan="1" ><b>Exclude</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div> <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!acc.member.Excluded__c}"/></td>
    <td colspan="1" ><b>Contact attempt</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div> <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!acc.unsuccessful}"/></td>
    <td colspan="1" ><b>Save</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div> <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!acc.needsUpdate}"/></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><b>Comments</b><apex:inputField style="width:95%;" value="{!acc.member.Comments__c}"/></td>
    <td colspan="1" ><b>Churn</b> <div style="display:inline-block;width:5%;"></div> <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!acc.churn}"/></td>
    <td colspan="6" style="text-align:left;"><b>Level of Satisfaction Details</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>To review</b><apex:inputField value="{!acc.member.CommentToReview__c}"/><apex:inputField style="width:95%;" value="{!acc.member.LevelOfSatisfactionDetails__c}"/></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</apex:repeat>   
</table>
</div>  

    </apex:form>
    </body>      
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you check session setting ? http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/01/session-settings-in-salesforce.html

Comment: http://puu.sh/pfgsH/51f3ba45e4.png

I saw in another post that he solved by unclicking the last 2 clickjack options but in my case I have them already unclicked.

Comment: I recommend you start by adding some debug statements to your controller. If you're getting an invalid session error, I can't help but ask if you've enabled Lightning and have this running inside a Lightning I-frame? SessionIds for a VisualForce page are not the correct Id's. They need to come from the Lightning page they're wrapped in if you are.

Comment: No, we're not using anything related to Lightning pages/components in our org. :(

Comment: Have you checked the URL's that take them to your page, it could be a parameter on the page, at least that was the issue for a few others with that error http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116031/the-page-you-submitted-was-invalid-for-your-session/116202#116202

Comment: The url that takes me to that page is quite simple. 
https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/FarmingCampaignDetail?sfdc.tabName=01rb00000005isc
I already reviewed that post but couldn't see similarity with my case.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderAeonsTorn, were you able to resolve this problem? I'm having a related issue.

Comment: The error stopped appearing but I honestly don't remember changing anything relevant, so no, sadly I can't help you with it :(